# Can I set text under buttons in SOTabBar library?

Tags: swift, uitabbar, swift5

I use SOTabBar library and in documentation doesn't said anything about text under the tabs. Does anyone use it and was setting some text under it?

Does it solution to add some view under tab buttons with UILabels and set text? that wouldn't be responsive for all device...[That's my tab menu, at this point customers doesn't understand what tab means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRnMv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point is always the examples in the repository. Without knowing your current approach you can attempt something similar to this.

```
class ViewController: SOTabBarController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 2.248547389e-05, green: 0.7047000527, blue: 0.6947537661, alpha: 1)
        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarCircleSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        let homeStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HOME_ID")
        let chatStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CHAT_ID")
        let sleepStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SLEEP_ID")
        let musicStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MUSIC_ID")
        let meStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ME_ID")

        homeStoryboard.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_Selected"))
        chatStoryboard.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Chat", image: UIImage(named: "chat"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "chat_Selected"))
        sleepStoryboard.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Sleep", image: UIImage(named: "moon"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "moon_Selected"))
        musicStoryboard.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Music", image: UIImage(named: "music"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "music_Selected"))
        meStoryboard.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Me", image: UIImage(named: "menu"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "menu_Selected"))

        viewControllers = [homeStoryboard, chatStoryboard,sleepStoryboard,musicStoryboard,meStoryboard]
    }

}
```

Where you can access the titles, if needed, via `viewController.tabBarItem.title`

Link to the [relevant example](https://github.com/Ahmadalsofi/SOTabBar/tree/master/Example/SOTabBar)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Harry J, i reed documentation better and i solve my problem.